# distinguishability combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

There are nine labeled parking spots arranged in a row near a small hotel, as shown
below. How many ways are there to park three cars and two vans given that vans occupy two
parking spots? All cars and vans are distinguishable from each other.

Comment: This forum usually downvotes posts that don't offer the poster's own attempt, so try to include that next time.

Comment: @AW23: The simplest way is to imagine that the vans have "eaten up" two spaces, and so we need to park $5$ "rightsized" vehicles in $7$ spots, thus $\binom75\cdot5! = 2520$

Answer (score 3):

We park the vans first, and there are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to do so. This is because the vans take up two spots, so each one requires an extra spot, thus there are only 7 spots we can choose from. We multiply this by $2!$ because there are 2 ways to permute these vans.

Now we park the cars, and we have used up four parking spaces (2 from each of the vans), so there are 5 spaces left. There are 3 cars, so there are $\binom{5}{3}$ ways to choose these spaces. We multiply this by $3!$ because there are $3!$ ways to permute these cars.

Our answer is then $\binom{7}{2}2!\binom{5}{3}3!=2520$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the distinguishability, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Number the parking spaces $1$ through $9$. We first choose spaces for the two vans. Say that one van occupies spaces $k$ and $k+1$, while the other occupies spaces $\ell$ and $\ell+1$, with $k<\ell$. Then we must have $1\le k<k+2\le\ell\le 8$, so in particular $1\le k\le 6$. For each choice of $k$ we have $k+1<\ell\le 8$, so there are $8-(k+1)=7-k$ possible choices for $\ell$. Thus, there are

$$\sum_{k=1}^6(7-k)=\sum_{i=1}^6i=\frac{6\cdot7}2=21$$

possible choices for $k$ and $\ell$. The two vans are distinguishable, so they can fill any pair of spaces in $2$ different ways, and there are therefore $2\cdot21=42$ different ways to park the vans. They use up $4$ of the $9$ parking spaces, leaving $5$ for the $3$ cars. There are $\binom53$ ways to choose $3$ of the spaces, and the $3$ cars can then fill them in $3!$ different orders, so there are

$$\binom53\cdot3!=10\cdot6=60$$

ways to park the cars once the vans are parked. Putting the pieces together, we see that there are altogether

$$42\cdot60=2520$$

different ways to park the five vehicles.

Answer (score 1):

Put the five vehicles in order; this can be done in $5!=120$ ways.  They take up $7$ total parking spaces, leaving two unoccupied.  There are $6$ places (between vehicles or before or after all five vehicles) into which the two unoccupied spaces can go, so the two unoccupied spaces can be placed in ${{6}\choose{2}} + 6=15+6=21$ different ways per vehicle order, for a total of $120\cdot 21 = 2520$ parking configurations.